# Syntax error at UPDATE VB - when saving info to access

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I have a windows form with various textboxes and 1 label, the label Identifies my ID in my database, I essentially want to search find the record using the label (ID) and then update the row with the data in the textboxes.

I get syntax error when I carry out ds.update(da)

any ideas? I have no idea what it is holding me back I am assuming it is something silly.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [STG] WHERE [ID] like '" & Label15.Text & "%'" 'LABEL 15 CONTAINS DATABASE ID
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    ds = New DataTable
    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(ds)
    'conn.Close()


    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    ds.Rows(0).Item(1) = KKSTextbox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(1) = KKSTextbox.Text 'DATA I WISH TO STORE IN MY DATABASE
    ds.Rows(0).Item(2) = TypeTextbox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(3) = RangeTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(4) = CompDescTextbox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(5) = LRTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(6) = FuncLocTextbox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(7) = LocTextbox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(8) = MANTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(9) = PTNOTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(10) = SUPPTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(11) = DetailTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(12) = PIDTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(13) = CONNTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(14) = BLOCKTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(15) = OMTextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(16) = AL1TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(17) = AL2TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(18) = AL3TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(19) = AL4TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(20) = AL5TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(21) = AL6TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(22) = AL7TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(23) = AL8TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(24) = AL9TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(25) = AL10TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(26) = EFF1TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(27) = EFF2TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(28) = EFF3TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(29) = EFF4TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(30) = EFF5TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(31) = EFF6TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(32) = EFF7TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(33) = EFF8TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(34) = EFF9TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(35) = EFF10TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(36) = SET1TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(37) = SET2TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(38) = SET3TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(39) = SET4TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(40) = SET5TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(41) = SET6TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(42) = SET7TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(43) = SET8TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(44) = SET9TextBox.Text
    ds.Rows(0).Item(45) = SET10TextBox.Text
    da.Update(ds)
    'da.Dispose() 'I get syntax here
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the error? I might be wrong but is this .net or regular VB?

Answer (score 1):

Do use the command builder after the fill

```
Dim row As DataRow = ds.NewRow
'set all the values for row like row("columnName") = value
ds.Rows.Add(row)
da.Update(ds)
```

First you need to get a reference to a new row. Then set the values. Then add the new row to the DataTable and finally do the update